# Grep partial search but print whole matching word

Tags: search, grep

I have data in this tab separated format -

```
Sample1_iu Sample2_id Sample3_ab 233_Sample4_ss .... PART_Sample1442_22
```

Now, I have only Sample ID, i.e. only partially matching info. When I search with grep, I want to see the whole word.

Ex. When I search "Sample2" with grep, I want the output to be "Sample2_id"

grep -w and grep -o print the words which match. Since the data is tab separated, I'm not able to define a regex to isolate the information correctly. Should I even be using grep or try something else?

Answer (score 2):

```sh
$ s='Sample1_iu Sample2_id Sample3_ab 233_Sample4_ss .... PART_Sample1442_22'

# with GNU grep
$ echo "$s" | grep -wo '\w*Sample2\w*'
Sample2_id

# if \w isn't supported
$ echo "$s" | grep -wo '[[:alnum:]_]*Sample2[[:alnum:]_]*'
Sample2_id
```

If you want to match any character other than tab, you can use these:

```sh
# GNU grep with PCRE available
grep -woP '[^\t]*Sample2[^\t]*'

# with a shell that supports $'..' quoting
grep -wo $'[^\t]''*Sample2'$'[^\t]*'
```